# Deriving expected value of the size of a set

Tags: expected-value

I did an experiment with a die where I counted the number of occurrences of each value, and associated the values as an element in a set.

For example, here are the values I got when I rolled a die 18 times:

1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6

1 - 3 occurrences
2 - 3 occurrences
3 - 3 occurrences
4 - 3 occurrences
5 - 3 occurrences
6 - 3 occurrences

S = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }

E(|S|)=6

Another example (with a different biased die):

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 - 18 occurrences

S = { 1 }

E(|S|)=1

How do I derive the expected value of the size when the probability is not given and I only have the sample distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by "samples are unevenly distributed and the probability is unknown"? Are you saying you are not assuming it's a fair die?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to define a question, much less an answer!! By the way, asking "What is the formula" seems to presume there always is a "formula", even for a badly formulated question! Ain't so.

Comment: It's not a fair die, but we don't know the probability of each occurrence.

Comment: In that case, I don't see how there can be a formula.

Comment: @PeterFlom Is it not possible to derive an expected value from sample distribution?

Comment: This may be getting beyond my math-skills, or maybe I just don't understand your question, but wouldn't the expected value from a sample be the value you got? (like in the examples you give)

Comment: I think he means that the sample average would be an estimate of the expectation for that die.  My problem understanding this is with the term set size.  I am not clear as to why you want to define certain sets and determine the distribution of the size of the set. If the rolls are independent the resulting sample has a multinomial distribution and the sample proportions give estimates of the multinomials parameters.  So in large samples you will have an idea as to whether or not the die is biased and if so which numbers have the higher probabilities of occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the set is $|S(n)| = \sum_i I_i(n),$ a sum of the indicator random variables where $I_i(n) = 0$ if $i$ doesn't appear on any of the $n$ rolls, and $I_i(n) = 1$ if $i$ is rolled at least once.

By linearity of expectation, $E(|S(n)|) = \sum_i E(I_i(n)) = \sum_i P_i(n)$ where $P_i(n)$ is the probability that you see at least one $i$ in the $n$ rolls. If the probability of rolling an $i$ is $p_i$, then $P_i(n) = 1 - (1-p_i)^n.$ So, if you know the probabilities $p_i$, you can calculate $E(|S(n)|) = \sum_i 1-(1-p_i)^n.$

There are many choices about how you can estimate the $p_i$ from the experiment. One possibility is to choose a uniform prior distribution over the $n-1$-dimensional set of possible nonnegative values of $p_i$ adding up to $1$, a simplex. Then you update this prior acording to Bayes' Theorem and your data. The result is a [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) on the simplex with $\hat p_i = \frac{\#(i)+1}{n+v}$ where $v$ is the number of faces on the die and the $\hat p$ means it is an estimate. So, if you roll a $6$-sided die $18$ times and get $1$ each time, you would estimate $\hat p_1 = \frac{19}{24}$ and $\hat p_2= \hat p_3=\hat p_4=\hat p_5=\hat p_6 = \frac{1}{24}.$ This is not the only way to estimate the $p_i$, but the differences between consistent methods should be small if you have enough data.